# How to add terms and conditions in the ubercart?

Tags: 7, ubercart

I had tried [site displaimer](https://www.drupal.org/project/site_disclaimer) module.

It needs node *title* or *id*. What is the node *id* or *title* for *ubercart checkout page* ?

I also had tried [uc_tc](https://www.drupal.org/project/uc_tc) module. It seems only for drupal 6.

Any advice? I just need *terms and conditions* appear at *ubercart checkout page*.

Many Thanks

Comment: The ubercart checkout page doesn't have a nid (it's not a node). Making your Terms into a block and showing the block on the checkout page might be the simplest solution

Comment: Thanks Clive. I will use this method, but I hope ubercart can add this feature for drupal 7

Comment: Check out "[Ubercart Terms of Service](https://www.drupal.org/project/uc_termsofservice)" Module which is available for Drupal7 as Beta release, which should be working.